If $f$ has an absolute maximum at $x=3$, is it guaranteed to be continuous at $x=3$?
If a function $f$ has an absolute maximum at $x=3$, then is $f$ continuous at $x=3$?  I missed this question on Calc AB test and I want to make sure that I am not missing a key concept here.

consider f(x) = 0 for all x, except f(3) = 1.

How is absolute-continuity relevant here?

That is not true. For example define $f(x)=0$ for $x<3$, $f(x)=3$ for $x=3$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x>3$, then $f$ has a global maximum at $x=3$ but not continuous at $x=3.$

And global maximum is the same as absolute maximum?

$f$ has a global maximum at $x=3$ by definition means: $$\forall x\in Df , f(3)\geq f(x)$$
$f$ is continuous at $x=3$ by definition means: $$\lim_{x\to3}f(x)=\ell\in\mathbb{R}$$
So this is a case of "does $P\implies Q$ hold ?"
Short answer : No
Slightly longer answer : Not necessarily.
Lets define the function $g(x)=-|x-3|$ , $g$ has a maximum at $x=3$ and in continuous at $x=3$. So we know that $P\implies Q$ is not impossible because we found a case where it holds
Luckily @user1455996 has provided a perfect counter example where $P=$TRUE but $Q=$FALSE.

I'm a bit confused by this answer.  The question which I missed on the calc test said, "If f has an absolute max at x=3, then  f is continuous at x=3.  T or F.  I answered T.  The function that you gave IS continuous at x=3 and x=3 is the global max.  So seems this would support the answer of True
